# Move_base is not using plugin lib

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What can make move_base not using plugin????

When i launch my move_base on hydro i see alot of ROS_INFO "using plugin..." and rosparam tells me they are really loaded.

But when i launch move_base on another pc using groovy nothing was loaded...

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99121/move_base-is-not-using-plugin-lib.../) by [NunoFialho](https://answers.ros.org/users/8576/nunofialho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The costmaps in hydro are completely rewritten where each layer is a plugin. This functionality is not present in groovy where the entire costmap is a single library. This likely explains the differences in output that you see.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2